# TextBox.Text.Replace() MultiThreading

Tags: c#, multithreading

im using a textbox and need to replace text in the textbox. the problem is that i need to replace 718 different items. I would like to put each replace into its own thread to quicken   the process but when i do, it never replaces.

i have tried similar to the following

```
foreach (Match m in matchCollection)
{
ReplaceClass r = new ReplaceClass(TextBox,m,ReplaceText)
Thread th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(r.Replace))
th.start()
}
```

Comment: I don't see `th.Start()`. Also what does ReplaceClass look like?

Comment: 718 threads is just plain bad idea

Comment: I suggest not to manipulate the TextBox. Get the `Text` string from the 'TextBox`, do all the replacements and then assign result string to the textbox. You are not supposed to access UI elements from non-UI thread.

Comment: You can only work with controls from the UI thread. So you'll end up either with a bunch of exceptions or with your main thread doing all the work anyway

Comment: 718 modifications really isn't a lot. I would just use a `StringBuilder` for efficient string manipulation and forget the whole multithreading idea. (Assuming you're not talking about 718 *textbox controls*.)

Comment: the regex is finding the initial text "DECL E6POS test = {X 1000, Y 29, Z 9, A 5, B 3, C 6}" and im replacing the X,Y, and Z values of the strings in the instance. there is alot of other information in the text box (1700 lines). right now for the file it takes 30 seconds. If you guys tell me to accept the 30 seconds and move on then thats what ill do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dyppl wrote in a comment you can access a form only from the thread in wich it was declared and it's running.
I think that if you want to speed up the process don't replace the text in the text box but just copy the text in a temporary string , modify it (replace the matches ) and then overwrite the text in the form.
So

```
string text = TextBox.Text
foreach (Match m in matchCollection)
{
   text = somereplacement(m,replacetext);

}
TextBox.Text = text;
```

Edit:
As the Anthony Pegram says , it's not good to manipulate a string in such way inside a loop because the string gets created every time , but i don't know what your replace function does. A better way could be

```
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder(TextBox.Text);  
foreach (Match m in matchCollection)
{
   //do something
   .
   .
   .
   text.Replace( toreplace ,replacement);

}
TextBox.Text = text.toString();
```

Or you can also use the functions to search and replace of regular expressions. Just don't replace over the textbox because each time you make a replacement the  control has to be drawn again.

Comment: You really don't want to do manipulation of a `string` inside a loop. Can you think of a better way to perform the operation?

Comment: @N4rk0, `StringBuilder` is what I was hoping you'd mention. It is a class specifically built to manipulate strings, particularly when you have such manipulation happening inside a loop. (In small quantities, working directly against a `string` is absolutely fine.)

Comment: Yes but StringBuilder is useful when we build a string to avoid using the += operator. Here we don't need to build the string , just to replace some pieces. I think that the member functions of the string class are good for this taks. Am i wrong?

Comment: @N4rko, it's the same concept. `StringBuilder` supports more than just `Append` operations, and `+=` is not the only `string` operation that results in a *new* string. They all do! Replace, remove, insert, concat (append)... it's all the same relative cost. `StringBuilder` handles them all.

Comment: @Anthony Pegram: Thanks for mentioning that, I never knew that StringBuilders were so flexible! Excellent point =)

Comment: Right i should have wrote text = text.Replace() , i'm going to edit..my bad

Answer (score 0):

Multithreading won't really help you here, because you can't have all these threads accessing the same string to replace stuff, and the overhead of creating all these threads would outweigh any benefit anyway - Your computer doesn't have a 718 core CPU!

You're better off not using multithreading. Keep in mind that 718 replace operations might not actually be all that slow anyway, unless the string is huge.

Just do the replace operations without threading - If you want to add threading to your application, find an operation that takes several seconds, and doesn't all involve the same variable for the entire operation.